# Sessionhandler write does not work?

Tags: php, symfony, session

I work with symfony http-foundation/session for session storage in php.My problem is below code.

```
/**
 * Constructor.
 * Make sure your PHP session isn't already started before using the Session class.
 * If you have a legacy session system that starts your session
 * Symfony sessions are designed to replace several native PHP functions.
 * Applications should avoid using session_start(), session_regenerate_id(), session_id(),
 * session_name(), and session_destroy() and instead use the APIs in the following section.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $storage = new NativeSessionStorage(array(), new NativeFileSessionHandler(application.'/storage/session'));
    $this->session = new Session($storage);
    $this->session->start();

}
```

Session file has been created to specified directory When I worked the code but the writing process does not work when I set any data.

```
/**
 * {@set} .
 * Sets an attribute by key.
 */
public function set($key=null,$value=null)
{
    if($key!==null && $value!==null){
        return $this->session->set($key,$value);
    }
    return false;
}
```

What is problem ? .thanks for your reply.

Comment: These snippets of code don't make much sense in isolation (although the absence of any error checking/reporting hints to an exaplanation). Nor do your expectations - a session should not be written when a vaule is set - only when the session is saved.

Comment: symcbean what should I do? how it use?

Comment: I think what @symcbean wants to say is, you should add some more code when and where you call the constructor, and where you try to add an entry in the session. You have just posted isolated functions which are not giving any idea where or how you use them.